# how can it have no "list indices must be integers, not tuple"?

Tags: python, syntax

I am a little bit familiar with python, But I have met a problem banging my head. I used to operate arrays just like this:

```
Z=[['1','2','3'],['2','3','4'],['5','6','7']]
Z = Z[:][1:]
```

I know it cannot be substituted by `Z = Z[:，1:]` because it will show errormessage that 'list indices must be integers, not tuple'. But in one project I saw this piece of code that can also work:

```
for target_participant_counter in xrange(1,22):

  D = genfromtxt(participant_file, delimiter=',')

Z = vstack((Z,D))
```

`Z = Z[:,1:]`

I just cannot believe it can work. Could some one tell me how it can go through the compiler?

Comment: Can you please provide output which you want?

Comment: Seems like that project is using numpy, and `Z` is a numpy array, and numpy arrays can be indexed like that. Check the top of the project, it would be having `from numpy import <things>` .

Answer (score 0):

Python's `list` type is a plain array, which means it associates numbers from 0 to N with objects. Other than that, it is not a general associative container like the `map` type, which can take tuples as keys, too.

Just to make it clear, you didn't see anyone using a tuple as *list* index. What you saw was the use of a tuple as *key* in some other container! The syntax is basically the same, but the meaning still depends on the container. You can write your own containers, too, btw.